# How to get JComboBox Auto-suggestion

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, autosuggest, suggestbox

Friends, in this project I need a list suggestion as the user types. I have looked at many examples and have started work on it and it somewhat works. The problem is, it only shows the suggestions for the first letter typed and when the second letter is entered, the suggestions disappear.
Please help me figure out why.
My code is written so as to auto-complete with the first option in the list when the right arrow key is pressed.

```
Vector<String> v = new Stack<String>();
public JTextField tx;
private boolean hide_flag = false;
tx = (JTextField)name.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
tx.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                 String text = tx.getText().toUpperCase();
                 if(text.length()==0){
                 name.hidePopup();
                 setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(v),"");
                         }
                 else{
                     DefaultComboBoxModel m = getSuggestedModel(v,text);
                      if(m.getSize()==0){
                 name.hidePopup();
                      }
                      else{
                 setModel(m,text);
                  name.showPopup();
                      }
                 }

                }


            });
 }
        @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt){
 String text = tx.getText();
 int code = evt.getKeyCode();
 if(code == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
      if(!v.contains(text)){
                v.addElement(text);
          }
   hide_flag = true;
 }else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
 hide_flag = true ;
 }else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
   for(int i=0; i< v.size();i++){
       String str = (String)v.elementAt(i);
        if(str.startsWith(text)){
          tx.setText(str);
            return;
        }}
 }
 }
  });

  }
 private void setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel Mdl, String str) {
                    name.setModel(Mdl);
                    tx.setText(str);
                }
 private DefaultComboBoxModel getSuggestedModel(List<String> list , String text){
     DefaultComboBoxModel m = new  DefaultComboBoxModel(); 
     for(String s : list){
         if(s.startsWith(text)){
       m.addElement(s);  
     }
     }
     return m;
 }
```

I want the auto-complete to be able to suggest words as I type. More than just the first letter.

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` for `JTextComponent`. Use a `DocumentListener`

Comment: Thank you peeskillet.please suggest me some examples

Answer (score 0):

> "please suggest me some examples"

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are sooo many implementations out there already. Just do a Google search. Here are a couple

### SwingX

Maven Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

public class SwingXDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JComboBox comboBox;
                comboBox = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Ester", "Jordi",
                    "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi"});
                AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox);
                System.out.println("Is editable - "
                        + comboBox.isEditable() + ". Surprise!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, comboBox);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

### JIDE

Maven Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jidesoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jide-oss</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

import com.jidesoft.swing.AutoCompletionComboBox;

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JIDEDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AutoCompletionComboBox comboBox;
                Object[] elements = new Object[]{"Ester", "Jordi", "Jordina",
                    "Jorge", "Sergi"};
                comboBox = new AutoCompletionComboBox(elements);
                comboBox.setStrict(false);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, comboBox);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I have searched many times but i cannot find.can you suggest some examples with database connectivity,like my code